# New attribute where you can select products

Tags: attributes, product-attribute

In default magento there are 3 sections where you can select associated products: related, upsells and crossells.

I need a forth one.

How can you create such an attribute where you would be able to associate products?

Is there a simple admin way or a custom module is involved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [a free extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-accessories.html) for this.
It adds a new relation called `Accessories`. You can rename the label to anything else you need.
It says on Magento Connect that is compatible with 1.6 but it works nicely for 1.9 also.
The only downside to it is that it rewrites the product model (I wrote the extension when I was really young and unexperimented). If you don't like it that way, you can use it as a starting point at least.
The idea is to create a new relation type and clone the functionality for upsells.